# Increase the length of separator between list item

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the line separator height between li tags.

I have tried using `height:100%` but it is not working.

Am I following the right approach. Can anyone help?

CODE:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
li:first-child {
    border-left:none
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table  cellspacing="0px;" style="border-top-width:0.1px; 
     border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#ccc; border-bottom-color:#ccc; 
     border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:0.1px;">
  <tr>
    <td><ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
      </ul></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have set the `li` elements to `display:inline;`.  `inline` elements can't take `height`.  Instead, use either `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;` and `display:block;`

```
li {
    ...
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thks display:inline-block worked,but can u explain what is the use of  float:left here

Answer (score 0):

use the `margin` or `padding`:

**CSS**:

```
li {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height):

```
li {
    line-height: /*set height of li here */;
}
```

Text will be centered vertically. My preference, because it is effective for all `inline` and `block` elements, though one option among several.